# link to page when query is successful

Tags: php, mysql

```
$nieuweklant  = "INSERT INTO klanten (voornaam,achternaam,tussenvoegsel,email,telefoonnummer,woonplaats,nieuwsbrief) 
VALUES ('$voornaam','$achternaam','$tussenvoegsel','$email','$telefoonnummer','$woonplaats','$nieuwsbrief')";
mysql_query($nieuweklant) or die(mysql_error());
```

i would like to link to a page when the query above is succesfull

Comment: it won't work because when i open the page with the above query it redirects instant to the new page

Comment: If you put `header()` after the `... or die()`, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("Your Query Here");
if($query){

?>
<script>
window.location = "index.php" ;
</script>

<?php
}
?
```

>

Comment: it also redirect instant to index.php

Comment: you need redirect within refresh? if yes try using meta redirect 
`<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://xxx.com">`
or what you mean about instan redirect?

Comment: i'l explain: let me say my homepage is PAGE1 the page with the query is PAGE2 and the page where it must to redirect is PAGE3. i am on PAGE1 and i click on PAGE2 ( page with query) it instant links to PAGE3.